# Using an external variable

Tags: linux, file, shell, variables

I want to use a variable that I wrote in a file
into another file.
Example:
file `test1` has this code:

```
t=10
```

I want to use `echo $t` in another file, say named `test2`.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about shell scripts, you want to "source" the file with definitions, i.e., test2 should contain `. ./test1`.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to [`source`](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) the `test1` file from in the `test2` file.

#### test1

```
t=10
....
```

#### test2

```
. test1
echo $t
```